# Accept connection from outside of network behind a firewall

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, firewall, tcplistener

Currently I have written an app (kind of communication app) using TcpListener-TcpClient to connect clients to each-other and to the server.
(Clients should be able to connect to each other and also connect to the server at the same time).

The problem is the firewall applications users have. Their firewall app blocks incoming connection from outside of network completely.

(I tried to workaround this using windows firewall configuration script in vbscript with CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr") but it doesn't apply to firewall applications!)

What should I do?
Is there any workaround, or we just have to write manual for every firewall!

Additional notes:

Firewall applications like, kaspersky, node, zonealarm and ...

TeamViewer is a good example. How they did it?

We don't want the clients be dependent to the server. They should be able to connect to each other without using the server.

Comment: you can see how those programs do by using monitoring programs like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.com/) or [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is test for internet connection form the client then try to contact your server or any other client from the outside if not reply then ask or prompt the user "Are you using a firewall? most firewalls detect or notify the user of an "application attempting to contact" a server

Comment: You meant the "application is trying to act as a server" message right? Nope this doesn't work either! Firewall still blocks the port.

Answer (score 0):

If you could bypass all firewalls then they would be useless to have.  Even if they disable their software firewalls, they could still have a router acting as a firewall and not forwarding connection attempts.

If you have a dedicated server and allow clients to communicate to each other through that server, then firewalls shouldn't be a problem since each client initiates an outgoing connection to the server.

If you want a client to be able to act as a server, then that person will have to make sure to allow that application through their firewall.  Also, look into UPnP for opening ports on the router.

Comment: Do you have a link of an example app or an opensource project to see how it is implemented?

Comment: There weren't much information on that project. Anyway so it means in the client side, I will tell the client router to forward the specific port traffic to the client pc? won't this be blocked by firewall again?

Comment: Yes.  The difference is that most software firewalls prompt the user to allow or deny connections.  And it's fairly simple to make an exception with the Windows firewall using a single line of code, which is what most people have.  But most people don't know how to open ports on their router which is why UPnP is useful.